# Converting .java to .jar or .exe for a SINGLE .java file

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, exe

I've a single java file in my project which just fetches data from a SQL database and inserts it into Oracle database, it takes its input from a text file. The code runs perfectly, but now I am asked to make an .exe out of this java file.

I have googled and *stackled* for a solution but to no avail. All the questions and their respective answers deal with the Project as a WHOLE. I need to do it for just a single file. Also, I tried clean and build with NetBeans(on which I have written the java file) and it does make a .jar file, but is titled for the Project itself.

My project has some other java files which are totally unrelated. But I have kept them together as they are of the same type.

Any solution would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you are on windows, you can have a batch file  or shell script if linux which will execute the java file.

Comment: Does it **have to** be an executable or will a Batch file suffice?

Comment: This question is unclear to me. At first I thought it was how to make an EXE for a JAR, but it also sounds like how to *compile* a single (or select few) source files. Or maybe it is a combination of the two - but some clarification would be nice.

Comment: Put the `.class` into a Jar, with the correct `main-class` manifest entry, wrap the Jar into an executable using any of the availabe wrappers...

Comment: @Fildor I have been asked to create an executable file. So, exe it is.

Comment: @user2864740 The goal is that the guy above wants it to be portable and to be able to transfer the data at the click of a button. Or so he says.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it's just one file, why not copy and paste the code into a new project in NetBeans? This way you will leave your original project unchanged and compile your new project containing just the necessary code.

Comment: I will be trying that and let you know. But doesn't NetBeans only allow building jars? Does it allow jar to exe conversion too? I read that you need some kind of plugin to do that maybe.

Comment: May I ask why you specifically need an exe file? As this kills the purpose of Java being cross platform. I would suggest making a simple batch file to run the .jar file and just place them in the same folder.

Comment: I know it does. But, its not my call. I was told, and I did it. I can't believe my stupidity at a thing so simple! Thank, ou. Your answer was the first and it worked.

Comment: @ou_snaaksie Batch files are not very cross-platform either. Then what is the difference between a per-platform batch file and a per-platform executable file? That is, the cross-platform nature of Java can be utilized with the *source* and *run time environment*, even disregarding any packaging.

Answer (score 1):

Create a new project in Netbeans.

Copy all jars, necessary to support the database connection to this new project from your existing big project. Upon specifying these jars in the probject settings as library jars make sure that they will be packaged along with the compiled java class.

Copy your java class that makes this database connection.

Compile and build the new project.

Convert the generated jar file to the exe, using a "java to exe wrapper".

For instance: [Launch4J](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)

that's it.

Comment: Thanks, I created another project with just that single java file. Converted it to jar, which is executable in itself. I then converted it to exe. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

use the tool called Jsmooth. you can create a standalone .exe using it.
and for creating a .jar file.
In eclipse,

- Go to file menu
- select the EXport.. option
- select "as runnable jar file".

Comment: I was using NetBeans, and made a jar file. Then used launch4j.